# What does the system do between two Transaction Synchronization Manager log messages "Retrieved value [] for key []"?

Tags: java, spring, transactionmanager

I'm working on a Java web application that uses Spring and Informix database. Server with the web application and with the database are two different machines.

I noticed that one of the SQL queries takes more time to execute on the production server than on the test server. I took a look in the logs and saw that the most time consuming part of the whole transaction takes place between two messages of the Transaction Synchronization Manager.

This is the log entries of the transaction:

```
2021-02-23 13:04:07,968 DEBUG [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager] Using transaction object [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager$DataSourceTransactionObject@3f847659]
2021-02-23 13:04:07,969 DEBUG [org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationManager] Initializing transaction synchronization
2021-02-23 13:04:07,969 DEBUG [org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor] Getting transaction for [com.prod.service.material.MaterialService.getMaterialIds]
2021-02-23 13:04:07,969 DEBUG [com.prod.service.material.MaterialServiceImpl]  getMaterialIds 
2021-02-23 13:04:07,969 DEBUG [com.prod.dao.material.MaterialDaoJdbc]  getMaterialIds 
2021-02-23 13:04:07,969 DEBUG [com.prod.dao.material.MaterialDaoJdbc$MaterialListQuery] RdbmsOperation with SQL […] compiled
2021-02-23 13:04:07,969 DEBUG [org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate] Executing prepared SQL query
2021-02-23 13:04:07,969 DEBUG [org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate] Executing prepared SQL statement […]
2021-02-23 13:04:07,969 DEBUG [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils] Fetching JDBC Connection from DataSource
2021-02-23 13:04:07,969 DEBUG [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils] Registering transaction synchronization for JDBC Connection
2021-02-23 13:04:07,969 DEBUG [org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationManager] Bound value [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.ConnectionHolder@8bd3c80] for key [org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource@16aac72f] to thread [http-nio-127.0.0.1-8080-exec-21]
2021-02-23 13:04:07,972 DEBUG [org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils] Setting SQL statement parameter value: column index 1, parameter value [2010], value class [java.lang.String], SQL type 12
*2021-02-23 13:04:07,972 DEBUG [org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationManager] Retrieved value [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.ConnectionHolder@8bd3c80] for key [org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource@16aac72f] bound to thread [http-nio-127.0.0.1-8080-exec-21]
*2021-02-23 13:04:13,881 DEBUG [org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationManager] Retrieved value [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.ConnectionHolder@8bd3c80] for key [org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource@16aac72f] bound to thread [http-nio-127.0.0.1-8080-exec-21]
2021-02-23 13:04:13,881 DEBUG [org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor] Completing transaction for [com.prod.service.material.MaterialService.getMaterialIds]
2021-02-23 13:04:13,881 DEBUG [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager] Triggering beforeCommit synchronization
2021-02-23 13:04:13,881 DEBUG [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager] Triggering beforeCompletion synchronization
2021-02-23 13:04:13,881 DEBUG [org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationManager] Removed value [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.ConnectionHolder@8bd3c80] for key [org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource@16aac72f] from thread [http-nio-127.0.0.1-8080-exec-21]
2021-02-23 13:04:13,881 DEBUG [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils] Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource
2021-02-23 13:04:13,881 DEBUG [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager] Triggering afterCommit synchronization
2021-02-23 13:04:13,881 DEBUG [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager] Triggering afterCompletion synchronization
2021-02-23 13:04:13,881 DEBUG [org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationManager] Clearing transaction synchronization
```

The SQL query itself is pretty complex and returns around 2000 rows of data.

The Transaction Manager and Data Source are specified as:

```
 <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"> 
    <property name="driverClassName"><value>com.informix.jdbc.IfxDriver</value></property> 
    <property name="url"><value>jdbc:informix-sqli://app.prod.com:11111/prod:informixserver=prod</value></property> 
    <property name="username"><value>prod</value></property> 
    <property name="password"><value>1234</value></property> 
  </bean>    

  <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource">
          <ref bean="dataSource"/>
        </property>
      </bean>
```

System is:

```
OS: RHEL Server 7.9
Webserver: Tomcat 9.0.34
```

Why do we have those **two** messages from the Transaction Manager? Isn't it a single connection to the data source?

Also, what process can happen between those two messages that takes 6 secs to execute? Is the data being placed somewhere?

I ask because I don't know why it takes longer on the production server whereas on the test server with identical data it takes only 2 secs (between two messages I mentioned above).

Thank you!

### EDIT

The correct data source definition is as follows (I copied from the wrong file previously):

```
  <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName"><value>java:/comp/env/jdbc/MyDS</value></property>
  </bean>
  
 
  <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource">
      <ref bean="dataSource"/>
    </property>
  </bean>
```

And the context.xml file contains:

```
<Resource name="jdbc/MyDS"
          auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
          driverClassName="com.informix.jdbc.IfxDriver"
          url="jdbc:informix-sqli://app.prod.com:11111/prod:informixserver=prod;ifxIFX_LOCK_MODE_WAIT=20;ifxIFX_XASPEC=Y;" 
          username="prod" password="prod"
          maxActive="100" maxIdle="25" maxWait="10000"
          removeAbandoned="true" removeAbandonedTimeout="60" logAbandoned="true"/>
```

Comment: It is a single connection, since the `ConnectionHolder@8bd3c80` object has the same identity (although technically the holders can be reused), so it's just fetching it twice. But how come you've defined the datasource as a `DriverManagerDataSource`, yet the log says it's a DBCP datasource? Your test env and prod env don't seem to be the same, so YMMV with anything you try.

Comment: Yes, you are right, that was the wrong file. I added the right one. Thank you!